# jQuery: how do I add a div to the end of my HTML file?

Tags: jquery

I saw in the documentation that .append allows you to add things to an element. But I want to end a div right before the `</body>` tag

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('body').append('<div>footer</div>');
```

but also this:

```
$('<div>footer</div>').appendTo('body');
```

or this:

```
$('body').html($('body').html()+'<div>footer</div>');
```

Reference with differences here: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 5):

```
$('body').append('<div />');
```

Answer (score 2):

Wait, so why doesn't this work?

```
$("body").append('<div id="your_div" />');
```

Comment: didn't know the body was an attribute. =)

Comment: @DerNalia `body` is a `tag` and not an attribute... :)

Comment: @DerNalia `body` is not an attribute. In jQuery, it is a `selector`

Comment: Both correct. @DerNalia, you can use HTML tags, CSS selectors, and more as selectors in jQuery. Find out more on the doc pages of the selector engine jQuery uses, Sizzle (http://wiki.github.com/jeresig/sizzle/).